# meaningless char when image print with android

Tags: android, image, printing

How can print image with USB Adapter. I have error from attachment.

[image]

My code:

```
Bitmap bmp = getBitmapFromView(view);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
.....
.....
usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(usbEndpoint,byteArray,byteArray.length,10000);
```

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What's your question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: how can I print to image with USB adapter? I can print for value String but ı cant print image or pdf file.

Comment: How are we supposed to know? You haven't told us what the device is that you're trying to connect to over USB.

Comment: I trying connect to hermal receipt printer